# Is super slow Ubuntu 14.04 a graphics problem?

Tags: unity, 14.04, intel-graphics

We just installed 32 bit version of Ubuntu 14.04 on our old Dell Dimensions 2400. Everything seemed to load ok but Ubuntu is super slow. Several of the different threads I've read about this focus on the graphics card and/or its drivers.

Depending on how I go to read the system settings, either through the launcher or through the session indicator, I get different info. about the graphics card. Through the launcher I get i845Gx86/MMX/SSE2 which is what is actually installed. When I go through the session indicator I get Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe(LLVM 3.4, 128bits) instead. Is this a problem and if so, is it what's making Ubuntu run so slowly?

System info:

- Memory: 2.0GiB
- Processor: Pentium 4 2.8 GHz

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no hardware driver support for running the Unity desktop with GPU-acceleration. That's why it uses llvmpipe to still be able to display Unity. Other desktop environments might run faster, but these machines are over 10 years old, you should replace them if possbile.